# Unable to access REST web service with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, rest

I'm using ajax in a php file to try to access a webservice (RESTful) to try to show data/ add data.

The code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/TESTSSSS/webresources/model.etablissement";
            $('#bAdd').click(function () {
                if ($("#nom").val() != "" || $("#code").val() != "") {
                    var data = '{"idEtablissement":null,"nom":"' + $("#nom").val() + '","codePostal":' + $("#code").val() + '}';
                    $.ajax({
                        'method': 'POST',
                        'url': url,
                        'contentType': 'application/json',
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'data': data,
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert("success");
                        },
                        error: function (errMsg) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                    $("#nom").val("");
                    $("#code").val("");
                } else {
                    alert("Tous les champs doivent être remplis");
                }
            });
            $('#bAdd2').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Which does not work (the AJAX always returns the error).
However when copying the exact PHP page to HTML in a **different** web application (instead of PHP application) the code works just fine, so i'm guessing the problem is with some settings in my PHP application?

Is there an option i need to activate/deactivate so that my PHP application can successfully use ajax?

Comment: `different web application` this is the clue, maybe `http://localhost:8080/TESTSSSS/webresources/model.etablissement` is wrong? especially having in mind what localhost is

Comment: The link works just fine on Glassfish tests and the web application, but i'm not sure if it would cause a conflict with wampserver..

Comment: Just tried a non-local web service and it's the same issue, so i think we can exclude any conflict in localhost